# What's the good way to update token so user has no idea about it

Tags: android

I'm working on application which receives a token during login operation and it has to be refreshed after some period of time. During this refresh I show a ProgressDialog saying the relogin is being executing. I didn't see such a behavior in other applications assuming this is done another way. I can simply not show the ProgressDialog but this can lead to something unpredictable if user would do something during relogin, i.e. with an obsolete token. Please share your experience with such a case. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you know the time when it expires cant you just use  `Service` to update the token in background? This should avoid any thing from going wrong should the user do something else during the log in process.

Comment: Yes, I know the time when it expires. Thank for a tip, I'll check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my experience with tokens (that must be noted took some time to expire) when the user would make a request with an obsolete token, that would be acknowledged and he would be prompted to login again. I believe having to relogin every now and then is not a big deal, but again this depends on how quick the token expires.
In case you want to do the relogin in the background I would suggest getting a push notification that the token expired and renew it. In case the user does something at that point you would prompt  him to relogin.
Just my two pennies...